# Resharper yanks its own tail; Is it right the first time or the last?

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring, resharper

I had some verbose code:

```
private bool AnyUnselectedCombox()
{
    bool anyUnselected = false;
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ComboBox)
        {
            if ((c as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                anyUnselected = true;
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    return anyUnselected;
}
```

...that Resharper offered to elegantize with a LINQ expression like so:

```
return this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Any(c => (c as ComboBox).SelectedIndex == -1);
```

...but the subsequent Resharper inspection says about the code it generated (above): *"Type cast is redundant"* (referring to the "c as ComboBox" part), so that it ends up as:

```
return this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Any(c => c.SelectedIndex == -1);
```

Shouldn't Resharper generate Resharper-approved code? Or does it simply sometimes need two passes for it to fully "gird up its loins"?

Comment: The analysis simply doesn't go as deep on this. Feel free to request it on http://youtrack.jetbrains.net

Comment: You had two separate "problems" (I have that in quotes as they're subjective readability issues mostly) with your code.  Each transformation fixed the corresponding problem.

Comment: I sometimes run into the problem where ReSharper will suggest converting a foreach to LINQ and then complain that there is an access to a modified closure, which (to my knowledge) cannot be amended within LINQ. At that point I revert to the original code and suppress the ReSharper notice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, sometimes ReSharper corrects itself, requiring a second pass to get it "just right". I've always assumed it uses certain "safe templates" to do the conversion and in some cases some parts of the safe transformation aren't really needed.

All versions of the code are correct and equivalent though, the first "pass" is converting to Linq and the second "pass" removes some redundant code that the Linq transformation added.